# How to graph the derivative of this graph?

Tags: derivatives

[image]

This is my professor's answers. I don't get the first dotted line on the derivative graph. There seems to be nothing wrong with the original graph in that place. I get the second dotted line because there is a sharp turn in the original graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first dotted line shows the point at which the first graph is vertical.  This means that "the gradient is infinite" and "the derivative is infinite".  But a derivative must be a proper number, it can't be infinite, so the correct way to say this is that the derivative does not exist.

Comment: Sorry but where is the graph vertical and infinite?

Comment: I didn't say the graph was vertical and infinite, I said the graph is vertical and the **gradient** is "infinite".  I would point it out to you if you were here but that's the problem with doing things online ;-)  It's a point in the third quadrant, can you see it now?

Comment: oh my gosh i see it now! thank you so much! i have to look out for that!